# undefined control sequence in template document

Tags: citing, lists, enumerate, templates, document-classes

Following is the tex file I am having errors with

```
\documentclass[twoside,mtp]{iiitg}
\let\mydegree\degree
\let\degree\relax
% 
% The default format is appropriate for printing, with blank pages
% inserted after the preliminary pages in twoside mode so you can
% send it directly to a two-sided printer. Howev  er, for ETD
% submission the blank pages need to be removed from the final output.
% The following option does this for you:
%
%   etd     : Produces a copy with no blank pages in the preliminary section.
%             Remove this option to produce a version with blank pages inserted
%             for easy double sided printing.
%
% The rest of the class options are the same as the regular book class.
% A few to remember:
%
%   oneside : Produces single sided print layout (recommended for theses less than 50 pages)
%   twoside : Produces single sided print layout (the default if you remove oneside)
%
% The BYUPhys class provides the following macros:
%
%   \makepreliminarypages : Makes the preliminary pages
%   \clearemptydoublepage : same as \cleardoublepage but doesn't put page numbers
%                           on blank intervening pages
%   \singlespace          : switch to single spaced lines
%   \doublespace          : switch to double spaced lines
%
% --------------------------- Load Packages ---------------------------------

% The graphicx package allows the inclusion of figures.  Plain LaTeX and
% pdfLaTeX handle graphics differently. The following code checks which one
% you are compiling with, and switches the graphicx package options accordingly.



\usepackage{makecell,tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' col. type
%\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
%\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{changepage,ifthen}
%\textwidth 6.5in
%\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.5in}
%\textheight 10in
%\addtolength{\topmargin}{-1in}
\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{2}
%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{epsfig}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{arydshln}
%\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,verbatim,eufrak}
%\usepackage[dvips,colorlinks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered,citecolor=red,urlcolor=red]{hyperref}

%\usepackage{natbib,stfloats}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{xltabular}
%\usepackage{fixltx2e}
%\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
%\usepackage{breakurl}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\algtext*{EndIf}

%\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\kthead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries #1}}
%tapas added above 3 lines


\usepackage{comment}
%above line added by 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}

%\usepackage[lined,algonl,algochapter,algoruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{gensymb}
%\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\newcommand {\g}[1]{\textcolor[gray]{0.6} {#1}}
\newcommand{\todo}[1]{\textcolor{red}{TODO: #1}\\}
\newcommand{\done}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{Tried to address. #1}\\}

% these are for the algorithms style file, for writing algorithms
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
%\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\begin{small}/* #1 */\end{small}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{/* #1 */}

% The fancyhdr package allows you to easily customize the page header.
% The settings below produce a nice, well separated header.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \fancyhead{}
  \fancyhead[LO]{\slshape \rightmark}
  \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\textbf{\thepage}}
  \fancyhead[RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
  \fancyfoot{}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername \ \thechapter \ \ #1}{}}
  \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection \ \ #1}}

% The caption package allows us to change the formatting of figure captions.
% The commands here change to the suggested caption format: single spaced and a bold tag
% Change the \DeclareCaptionFormat line below to make the captions fully bold
\usepackage{caption}
%\DeclareCaptionFormat{suggested}{\singlespace#1#2 #3\par\doublespace}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{suggested}{\singlespace \textbf{#1}\textbf{#2}#3 \doublespace}
\captionsetup{format=suggested}

%To instruct Latex to try to fit each paragraph into 1 less line
%\let\markeverypar\everypar
%\newtoks\everypar
%\everypar\markeverypar
%\markeverypar{\the\everypar\looseness=-1\relax}

%\newcommand{\captionfonts}{\small}

% The cite package cleans up the way citations are handled.  For example, it
% changes the citation [1,2,3,6,7,8,9,10,11] into [1-3,6-11].  If your advisor
% wants superscript citations, use the overcite package instead of the cite package.
\usepackage{cite}
%\usepackage[tone]{tipa}

% The makeidx package makes your index for you.  To make an index entry,
% go to the place in the book that should be referenced and type
%  \index{key}
% An index entry labeled "key" (or whatever you type) will then
% be included and point to the correct page.
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

%\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
%\urlstyle{rm}
% kodie commented above 2 lines
% If you have a lot of equations, you might be interested in the amstex package.
% It defines a number of environments and macros that are helpful for mathematics.
% We don't do much math in this example, so we haven't used amstex here.
%
% To include a link in your pdf use \href{URL}{Text to be displayed}.  If your
% display text is the URL, you probably should use the \url{} command discussed
% above.
%
% To add a bookmark in the pdf you can use \pdfbookmark.  You can look up its usage
% in the hyperref package documentation
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered,pdfpagelabels=true,plainpages=false,colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}
%commented above 4 lines
%changed urlcolor=blue to black
% ---------------- Fill in these fields for the preliminary pages -------------------
%
% For Senior and honors this is the year and month that you submit the thesis
% For Masters and PhD, this is your graduation date

\newcommand{\bigsize}{\fontsize{14pt}{20pt}\selectfont}

\Year{1988}
\Month{May}
\Author{Someone}
\mydegree{Master }
% If you have a long title, split it between two lines. The \TitleBottom field defines the second line
% A two line title should be an "inverted pyramid" with the top line longer than the bottom.
\TitleTop{{\bigsize \bf Anomaly Detection in Cloud Computing}}
%\TitleBottom{{\bigsize \bf  MEMORY SYSTEMS }}
%\TitleBottomagain{{\bigsize \bf MEMORY SYSTEMS}}
% Your research advisors
\AdvisorA{{Professor}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% APPROVAL BY DSC %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%\Approval{
%\singlespace
%\hspace{6cm}
%%Date:\hspace{.8cm}$\backslash \ \ \ \ \  \ \backslash$ 20  \\  \\
%Date:\hspace{.8cm}$/ \ \ \ \ \  \ /$ 20  \\  \\
%Certified that the thesis entitled {\bf ``TITLE OF THE THESIS''} submitted by NAME OF THE AUTHOR to the 
%
%\vspace{0.5in}
%
%%\noindent
%%Signature:~~~~~~~~~~\hfill Signature:~~~~~\hfill Signature:\hfill~
%
%%\noindent
%%Name:~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\hfill Name:~~~~~~~~~~\hfill Name:~~~~~\hfill~
%
%\vspace{1in}
%\noindent
%(Member)~~~~~\hfill(Member)~~~~~\hfill(Member)
%
%\vspace{0.3in}
%%\hspace{2cm}
%%Signature:
%\vspace{1in}
%%\hspace{2cm}
%%Name:
%\noindent
%%\hspace{2cm}
%(Supervisor) %~~~~~\hfill(Supervisor 2)
%
%
%
%\vspace{0.3in}
%
%%\hspace{2cm}
%%Name:~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\hfill Name:~~~~~\hfill ~~~~
%
%%\vspace{1in}
%%%\hspace{2cm}
%%\noindent
%%(External Examiner)\hspace{0.8in}(Chairman)
%}


\fussy

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}


\normalsize
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}
%\newfloatcommand{capbtabbox}{table}[][\FBwidth]
%\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
%\graphicspath{ {/home/arya/Desktop/synopsis_seminar/figures/} }
\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }


\begin{document}
 % Start page counting in roman numerals
 \frontmatter

 % This command makes the formal preliminary pages.
 % You can comment it out during the drafting process if you want to save paper.

\makepreliminarypages

 \singlespace

 \clearemptydoublepage
\thispagestyle{empty}

 \hspace{-0.4cm}{\huge \textbf{List of Abbreviations}}\\
 %  \end{center}
\input{texfiles/abrreviation}

\clearemptydoublepage
\thispagestyle{empty}

 %\hspace{-0.4cm}{\huge \textbf{List of Symbols}}\\
 %  \end{center}
%\input{texfiles/symbol}
%above three lines commented by tapas removing symbol table
\clearemptydoublepage
%\makepreliminarypages
 % Make the table of contents.
 \tableofcontents

 \clearemptydoublepage

 % Make the list of figures
 \listoffigures
 \clearemptydoublepage

 % Make the list of tables
 \listoftables
 \clearemptydoublepage

%\phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Symbols and Abbreviation}
%\include{files/symb_b}
%\include{files/symb_b1}
%\clearemptydoublepage

\onehalfspace

 % Start regular page counting at page 1
\mainmatter
\addtolength{\parskip}{0.05\baselineskip}

\abovedisplayskip=13pt
\belowdisplayskip=13pt

\clearemptydoublepage
\input{texfiles/chapter1}
\clearemptydoublepage
\input{texfiles/chapter2}
\clearemptydoublepage
\input{texfiles/chapter3}
\clearemptydoublepage
\input{texfiles/chapter4}
\clearemptydoublepage
\input{texfiles/conclusion}
\clearemptydoublepage

%\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
%\clearemptydoublepage
%\singlespace
%\bibliography{biblio}


  %\cite{*}
 %\bibliographystyle{plain}
 %\bibliographystyle{alpha}
  \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
  \clearemptydoublepage
  \bibliography{biblio.bib}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}

%\input{texfiles/flat}
%\clearemptydoublepage
%\input{texfiles/nest}
%\clearemptydoublepage
%\input{texfiles/intent}
%\clearemptydoublepage
%\input{texfiles/lm}
%\clearemptydoublepage
%\input{texfiles/conclusions}
%\clearemptydoublepage

%\appendix

%\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
%\clearemptydoublepage
%\singlespace
%\bibliography{thesis}

% \include{AppendixA}
% \clearemptydoublepage
% \include{AppendixB}
% \clearemptydoublepage

%\phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1} \small \normalsize
 \clearemptydoublepage

\phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Author's Biography} %Optional
\input{texfiles/cv}
\end{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\if 0

\begin{figure}[tb]
\centerline{
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{./figures/}
}
\caption{{\bf }}
\label{fig:}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure*}[tb]
\centerline{
\subfloat[{\bf }]{\includegraphics[height=0.3\textwidth,width=3.5cm,angle=-90]{./figures/}}
\hfil
\subfloat[{\bf }]{\includegraphics[height=0.3\textwidth,width=3.5cm,angle=-90]{./figures/}}
\hfil
\subfloat[{\bf }]{\includegraphics[height=0.3\textwidth,width=3.5cm,angle=-90]{./figures/}}
}
\caption{{\bf }}
\label{fig:}
\end{figure*}

\fi
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

I get error 
in lines

```
\makepreliminarypages
Undefined control sequence 
The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
```

and

```
\input{texfiles/chapter4}
\clearemptydoublepage
```

The moment I do in chapter 2 line 43

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item IaaS is a cloud service 
    \item IaaS providers include 
    \item Users: IT Administrators
\end{enumerate}
```

I get error

```
Undefined control sequence . The compiler is having trouble understanding command.
```

I don't have any cls file with me given to us.Here is the [full template](https://github.com/kiotie32/original-template) if it can give any clue.

Comment: Welcome. Please show the exact error message from the log file.

Comment: You not load/use `BYUPhys` document class. BTW, some packages you load twice.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/543468/134144

Comment: That error message, "The compiler is having trouble...", doesn't come from TeX. A bit of google suggests it comes from sharelatex. Is that the case? @leandriis is probably right, but should not have linked a question where he/she points to yet another question :-)

Comment: Welcome to TeX - LaTeX! Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code can be improved (some packages are loaded twice).  You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.